# ViewController.swift may not load correctly

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, opentok

I'm using xcode 6 and swift to make an app with video chat - using OpenTok.
i have 2 scenes "Menu" and "Video". From menu i use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("StreamScene", sender: self)
```

inside a button to go to "video" viewcontroller. The first time i load my APP everything works perfect, but when i navigate back from from "Video" to "Menu", and then again navigate from "Menu" to "Video" i t doesn't work i can't see the subscriber to my session, but when i close my APP but still let the video session run and start up my app again and navigate to "Video" viewcontroller it works - It is because my ViewControler may not load correctly?. I also use perfomrSegueWithIdentifier to navigate back.

code from video viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

//Api key
private let ApiKey = "45309032"
//Session ID
private let SessionID = HttpPost.SessionId
//Token
private let Token = HttpPost.Token

let SubscribeToSelf = false
class ViewController: UIViewController, OTSessionDelegate,     OTSubscriberKitDelegate, OTPublisherDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var DoctorDeclienBtn: UIButton!

var Session : OTSession?
var Publisher : OTPublisher?
var Subscriber : OTSubscriber?

var http = HttpPost()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Step 2: As the view comes into the foreground, begin the connection process.
    //ConnectToSession()
    println("Session ID " + SessionID)
    println("Token " + Token)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Step 1: As the view is loaded initialize a new instance of OTSession

    if(HttpPost.Role == "0")
    {
        DoctorDeclienBtn.hidden = true
    }


    ConnectToSession()


}


@IBAction func GoBackBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("a", sender: self)
    DisconnectSession()
}



@IBAction func DoctorDeclineBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    http.HttpPostVideoEnded("access_token=" + HttpPost.AccessToken, URL: "http://95.85.53.176/nhi/api/app/consultation/end/", completionHandler: {(EndSuccess: Int32) -> () in

        if(EndSuccess == 1)
        {
            if let session = self.Session
            {
                var Error : OTError?
                session.disconnect(&Error)


                if let error = Error
                {

                }

            }

        }


    })
}


// MARK: - OpenTok Methods

/**
* Asynchronously begins the session connect process. Some time later, we will
* expect a delegate method to call us back with the results of this action.
*/
func ConnectToSession ()
{

    Session = OTSession(apiKey: ApiKey, sessionId: SessionID, delegate: self)

    if let session = self.Session
    {
        var Error : OTError?
        session.connectWithToken(Token, error: &Error)


        if let error = Error
        {

        }

    }
}

/**
* Sets up an instance of OTPublisher to use with this session. OTPubilsher
* binds to the device camera and microphone, and will provide A/V streams
* to the OpenTok session.
*/

func PublishToSession()
{

    Publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self)

    var Error : OTError?

    Session?.publish(Publisher, error: &Error)

    if let error = Error
    {
        //Some message
    }


    //The resolutuon of current device
    var sizeRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
    var width = sizeRect.size.width
    var height = sizeRect.size.height

    Publisher!.view.frame = CGRect(x: width-(width/4), y: height * (4/5), width: width/4, height: height/3)
    view.addSubview(Publisher!.view)


}


//Unpublish to session
func UnPublishToSession()
{
    Publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self)

    var Error : OTError?

    Session?.unpublish(Publisher, error: &Error)

    if let error = Error
    {
        //Some message
    }

    Publisher!.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.Publisher = nil

}


/**
* Instantiates a subscriber for the given stream and asynchronously begins the
* process to begin receiving A/V content for this stream. Unlike doPublish,
* this method does not add the subscriber to the view hierarchy. Instead, we
* add the subscriber only after it has connected and begins receiving data.
*/
func SubscribeToStream(stream : OTStream) {
    if let session = self.Session {
        Subscriber = OTSubscriber(stream: stream, delegate: self)

        var Error : OTError?
        session.subscribe(Subscriber, error: &Error)
        if let error = Error {

        }
    }
}

func DisconnectSession()
{
    if let session = self.Session
    {
        var Error : OTError?
        session.disconnect(&Error)


        if let error = Error
        {
            NSLog("Disconnect failed")
        }

    }
}

/**
* Cleans the subscriber from the view hierarchy, if any.
*/
func UnsubscribeStream() {
    if let subscriber = self.Subscriber {
        var Error : OTError?
        Session?.unsubscribe(Subscriber, error: &Error)
        if let error = Error {

        }

        subscriber.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.Subscriber = nil
    }
}

// MARK: - OTSession delegate callbacks

func sessionDidConnect(session : OTSession) {
    NSLog("sessionDidConnect (\(session.sessionId))")

    // Step 2: We have successfully connected, now instantiate a publisher and
    // begin pushing A/V streams into OpenTok.
    PublishToSession()
}

func sessionDidDisconnect(session : OTSession) {
    NSLog("Session disconnected (\( session.sessionId))")
    UnPublishToSession()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("a", sender: self)
}

func session(session: OTSession, streamCreated stream: OTStream) {
    NSLog("session streamCreated (\(stream.streamId))")

    // Step 3a: (if NO == subscribeToSelf): Begin subscribing to a stream we
    // have seen on the OpenTok session.
    if Subscriber == nil && !SubscribeToSelf{
        SubscribeToStream(stream)
    }


}

func session(session: OTSession, streamDestroyed stream: OTStream) {
    NSLog("session streamDestroyed (\(stream.streamId))")

    if Subscriber?.stream.streamId == stream.streamId {
        UnsubscribeStream()
    }
    DisconnectSession()
}

func session(session: OTSession, connectionCreated connection : OTConnection) {
    NSLog("session connectionCreated (\(connection.connectionId))")
}

func session(session: OTSession, connectionDestroyed connection : OTConnection) {
    NSLog("session connectionDestroyed (\(connection.connectionId))")

}

func session(session: OTSession, didFailWithError error: OTError) {
    NSLog("session didFailWithError (%@)", error)

}

// MARK: - OTSubscriber delegate callbacks

func subscriberDidConnectToStream(subscriberKit: OTSubscriberKit) {
    NSLog("subscriberDidConnectToStream (\(subscriberKit))")


    var sizeRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
    var width = sizeRect.size.width
    var height = sizeRect.size.height

    if let view = Subscriber?.view {
        view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height + 20)
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(view)

    }
}

func subscriber(subscriber: OTSubscriberKit, didFailWithError error : OTError) {
    NSLog("subscriber %@ didFailWithError %@", subscriber.stream.streamId, error)

}

// MARK: - OTPublisher delegate callbacks

func publisher(publisher: OTPublisherKit, streamCreated stream: OTStream) {

    NSLog("publisher streamCreated %@", stream)


    // Step 3b: (if YES == subscribeToSelf): Our own publisher is now visible to
    // all participants in the OpenTok session. We will attempt to subscribe to
    // our own stream. Expect to see a slight delay in the subscriber video and
    // an echo of the audio coming from the device microphone.

    if Subscriber == nil && !SubscribeToSelf{
        SubscribeToStream(stream)
    }


}

func publisher(publisher: OTPublisherKit, streamDestroyed stream: OTStream) {
    NSLog("publisher streamDestroyed %@", stream)

    if Subscriber?.stream.streamId == stream.streamId {
        UnsubscribeStream()
    }
}

func publisher(publisher: OTPublisherKit, didFailWithError error: OTError) {
    NSLog("publisher didFailWithError %@", error)
}

func showAlert(message: String) {
    // show alertview on main UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let al = UIAlertView(title: "OTError", message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    }
}

}
```

Comment: can you post some code from the viewDidLoad bit of your video viewController, also the viewWillAppear bit? Basically if its not working as you described the problem will be in there somewhere

Comment: I have added my whole "Video" viewcontroller @fr0s1yjack. Thank for your reply

Comment: what happens if you put ConnectToSession() inside the viewDidLoad instead of viewWillAppear?

Comment: nothing change - i get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully consider the logic around the transitions.

In the code you provided, you basically say: "When the subscriber's stream is destroyed, unpublish and unsubscribe from the stream, and transition back to the Menu".

First, you should pay attention to where you want to clean up which kinds of state. As is, you assume that the other participant will leave, and then cleanup and transition all within the `session:streamDestroyed:` method. Instead, use that method to clean up just the subscriber. Similarly, clean up the publisher inside the `sessionDidDisconnect:` method. By clean up, I basically mean invoking the `UnsubscribeToStream()` and `UnPublishToSession()` methods respectively.

Next, the question of what it takes to trigger ending the call is something you should consider. Assuming that the other participant will leave first is okay for simple cases, but its a better design to make a method for this discrete action so that you can call it from more than one place. In terms of what the method needs to do, its actually as simple as calling `session.disconnect()`. That will trigger both the above methods that clean up the publisher and subscriber. Right now, you completely miss disconnecting and thats the reason that you don't start subscribing when you come back to the "Video" view (all the code to set up the call is only called from inside the `sessionDidConnect:` method).

Lastly, the segue needs to be triggered. In my opinion you should do this at the end of the `sessionDidDisconnect:` method, after you've cleaned up the publisher.

Comment: Hello @Ankur. Thank for your answer. Sorry I haven't been able to give you a feedback before now. I just started up this project again. I tried your solution but it still does not work. I have edited my answer to my newest solution. As you can see I disconnect when I go back to Menu view. And from Menu view i navigate to Video view and start Connecting again. My Subscriber does not load and i get a error saying: {NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out while attempting to subscribe to the stream.}

Comment: @LocDaiLe does this error happen consistently or just intermittently? that specific error has to do with network connectivity. try the OpenTok Connectvity Doctor [https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opentok-connectivity-doctor/id902048239?mt=8] on the device to see if the network is configured properly.